# Netextender disconnecting on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, vpn

I'm using netextender to connect to my company's network. It does connect, whether I use the gui or the cli, but after a few minutes it just stops receiving and or sending packages. I tried these solutions [How to get Netextender (VPN) working in Ubuntu 12.10 x64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246332/how-to-get-netextender-vpn-working-in-ubuntu-12-10-x64) but none of them work. Any advice on what to do? I can even use an alternative if it's recommended

Comment: Any solution found? please share I'm facing the same problem